Using mathplotlib in jupyter lab causes kernel to die
Using matplotlib.pyplot to create a figure works on a local python project, but in a jupyter lab enviroment, with the same code, it causes the kernel to die.
Older issues suggested downgrading freetype from 2.11 to 2.10.
But I use version 2.12.1 in both the pycharm and de jupyter version of the project, but 1 works and the other doesn't. this doesn't seem to be the solution.
Others also suggested trying:
import os
os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"

This wasn't the solution either
my code:
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

batch_size = 32
img_height = 180
img_width = 180

data_dir = pathlib.Path("./data_dir").with_suffix('')
output_dir = pathlib.Path("./ds_out").with_suffix('')

ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  labels='inferred',
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

class_names = ds.class_names
print(class_names)

ds.save(str(output_dir))

loaded_ds = tf.data.Dataset.load(str(output_dir))

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
for images, labels in loaded_ds.take(1):
  for i in range(9):
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1)
    plt.imshow(images[i].numpy().astype("uint8"))
    plt.title(class_names[labels[i]])
    plt.axis("off")

plt.show()

Edit:
I tried a simpler example in a new notebook:
# importing matplotlib module 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt 
 
# x-axis values 
x = [5, 2, 9, 4, 7] 
 
# Y-axis values 
y = [10, 5, 8, 4, 2] 
 
# Function to plot 
plt.plot(x, y) 
 
# function to show the plot 
plt.show()

This also kills the kernel unless I remove both these lines:
# Function to plot 
plt.plot(x, y) 
     
# function to show the plot 
plt.show()


It might be your code to blame. Please show it

Did not think it was relevant as it works in a regular pycharm project. but updated the question anyway to be sure

Do you use %matplotlib inline in jupyter (e.g. after import matplotlib.pyplot as plt) ? Otherwise it maybe tries to open a new window, and from browser it just can't

I tried that, but it made no difference both in my code and the simplified example

What if you don't plt.show()? It's not necessary in jupyter cells

the simple example now returns [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x28f1e137810>] and then the kernel still dies.
In my own code the kernel still just dies.
Tried both with and without %matplotlib inline

What do you mean specifically by, "Using matplotlib.pyplot to create a figure works on a local python project, but in a jupyter lab enviroment"? Are you running this not locally? Where? What do you mean by "jupyter lab enviroment"? What versions are you talking about? Your simple example code works fine in JupyterLab Version 3.4.8 and JupyterLab Version 4.1.5. I can point you to sessions served via the MyBinder service where it works fine. Thus, this is not general and you want to be looking at your environment. How did you install JupyterLab? Did it work before?

yes technically they both run locally. what i meant to say is that the code doesnt run when in a jupyter lab notebook. but when i copied it into a pycharm project, it did run.
It has never run in the notebook, i installed jupyterlab with pip

None of the regular fixes worked for me, so I decided to try again.
I created a fresh venv, and from that a new ipython kernel, and used that kernel in jupyterlab.
The issue is fixed by circumventing the old kernel, but it is weird that I did the same thing twice and on one it works and in the other it doesn't.
